# How to synchronize updates at different sites? .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, synchronization

I need to synchronize 2 sites content. Every post in first should be mirroring at second and vice versa. What is the best way to do it using .Net - just simple web service which check every time interval updates and post it, or maybe smth else, like sync framework? can't find good example to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL server you might also want consider:

- SQL Server's replication.
- SQL log shipping